# Intent Extra not equating to its value within if statement

Tags: java, android

This is my first question posted here so I hope I've explained the issue I am having thoroughly and clearly. Any/all help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the java files I'm working on:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton name1Button;
    ImageButton name2Button;
    ImageButton name3Button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Layout contains 3 ImageButtons "@+id/imageButton1", "@+id/imageButton2" and "@+id/imageButton3"

        name1Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        name2Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        name3Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    }

    public void onChangeScreen(View view) {
        Intent changeScreenIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

        if(view == name1Button) {
            changeScreenIntent.putExtra("Name", "name1");
        } else if (view == name2Button) {
            changeScreenIntent.putExtra("Name", "name2");
        } else if (view == name3Button) {
            changeScreenIntent.putExtra("Name", "name3");
        } else {
            changeScreenIntent.putExtra("Name", "Other");
            }
        startActivity(changeScreenIntent);
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout); //Contains a TextView "@+id/textViewName"

        Intent myIntent = getIntent();
        String strName = myIntent.getExtras().getString("Name"); //Set strName to the parsed name ("name1", "name2" or "name3")
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        myTextView.setText(strName); //Sets the name parsed to a TextView //Setting the texts of the displayed TextView "@+id/textViewName" to the value of strName. This CORRECTLY shows the parsed name.

        if(strName == "name1") { // Never true, even though the value of strName is "name1"
            //Do thing if certain button clicked
            Toast.makeText(this, "You selected name1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //Do other thing if non-specified button clicked
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

What this is meant to do is as follows:

- MainActivity displays 3 buttons.
- The user presses 1 of the 3 buttons, all of which call `onChangeScreen`.
- Depending on which of the 3 buttons was used to call `onChangeScreen`, a different value (string) is passed to SecondActivity.
- After setting the string to be passed to SecondActivity (using an if statement and `changeScreenIntent.putExtra()`, the second Activity is called.
- SecondActivity displays a single text box, which is set to the value passed using the `.putExtra()`.
- An if statement is then used to perfom some action based on the string passed, which is essentially basing it on which button called the SecondActivity.

This is where the issue arises. The if statement comparing the string passed into SecondActivity is 'apparently' not equal to the value of the string (yet the displayed `TextView` shows this string). And so the code (replaced with a Toast) within the if statement is never used.

Comment: Have you called this method `onChangeScreen` via xml?

Comment: Compare chars using equals, compare chars using "=="..

Answer (score 1):

Always use for comparing string

```
if(strName.equals("name1"))
 Toast.makeText(this, "You selected name1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //Do other thing if non-specified button clicked
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

equals() instead of == for string.....

enjoy coding.....

Answer (score 1):

Use `"name1".equals(strName)` instead of `==`. And in case `strName` is ever `null`.

Comment: I'm also a fan of putting the string constant first to avoid the null check, even if it doesn't look quite as nice.

Answer (score 0):

compare string using `equals` instead of `==`

Use

```
if(strName .equals("name1"))
```